# creating an attribute that contains a list of objects node js

Tags: node.js

Im new using node js , what im trying to do is creating an attribute that contains a list of projects in the userSchema so i can display the projects when the user log in in my electron app

this is my userschema :

```
var UserSchema = new Schema(
    {
  username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },

  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
  },
  nom: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  prenom: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },

  verif_code: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
}, { timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at' } });
```

and this is my projectSchema :

```
var ProjectSchema = new Schema(
    {
  description: {
    type: String,
   
  },
    useremail: {
    type: String,
  
  },
  imageurl: {
    type: String,
 
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var UserSchema = new Schema(
    {
  username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },

  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
  },
  nom: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  prenom: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },

  verif_code: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
  projects: [{type: Types.ObjectId, ref: 'projects'}],//projects is name of table in database
}, { timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at' } });
```

Comment: thank you for your answer still having this problem Types is not defined

Comment: If you are using mongoose then you can import Types mongoose and use it like above